# Error? in move_base.cpp executeCycle(...)

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm currently working with move_base.cpp in hydro (though I saw that the same applies to the other versions too), and I noticed that at https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/jade-devel/move_base/src/move_base.cpp#L787 the oscillation_pose_ (which is a private variable of the class) is never initialized somewhere in the code. So I wonder what's happening here.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210888/error?-in-move_base.cpp-executecycle(...)/) by [dimkirt](https://answers.ros.org/users/21067/dimkirt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2015-06-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's slightly lazy not to initialize it explicitly, but its initialized to 0,0,0.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2015-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dimkirt](https://answers.ros.org/users/21067/dimkirt/) on 2015-06-09**:
Hello David, thanks for your answer.
Also, I'm wondering what happens with orientation and the header (though they don't play any part in this case) of the PoseStamped message. Plus, where can I find the default inits for each message?
TIA

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-06-09**:
The default is for numbers to be 0 and the strings are empty.